# _origData is null for some models in Magento 2 before or after save

Tags: magento2, event-observer, repository

Let's get a customer save process from the admin panel as an example. We have an event observer for `model_save_before` and trying to get a set of values for the model that have been changed upon the saving process. 
On the customer model load in `\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel::load` we have a correct value in the model's _origData property. However, during the saving process the system goes through `\Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository::save` and we have the customer model with _origData property empty in the model_save_before (or even model_save_after) event observer after. Is there some way to get the customer's _origData somehow and don't have it cleared in the middle of the saving process? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **customer_save_after_data_object** event instead of customer_save_* events.

```
$dataObject = $observer->getEvent()->getData('customer_data_object');
$origDataObject = $observer->getEvent()->getData('orig_customer_data_object');
```